# What is considered suprise

Tags: world-in-flames

Assume the following situation:

Italy at war with France but not CW. Italian navy is in port in La Spezia, along with one German SUB and a German AA. CW DOWs Italy.

In the port strike:

- Are the Italian units considered surprised if the German SUB is not included in the combat?
- Can the German AA fire if the German SUB is not included?

Surprise rules on naval combat and port strikes say surprise occurs if only units of the surprised major or minor is involved in the combat.

Obviously, the Italians are surprised, and the Germans aren't - and the Germans decide whether to include the SUB or not.

Is a non-included SUB "involved"?

Answer (score 1):

I got this answer anecdotally at [my gaming club](https://www.facebook.com/groups/11910615724/10152423066995725/) (sorry about the facebook link, I'll post the discussion here when it halts or reaches a conclusion):

> In a port-strike your subs are automatic involved in a minor port. You cannot choose to be non-included in port.

No reference, but at least it's a ruling of some sort.